# How to use IContextMenu or Windows Shell ContextMenu on QT

Tags: windows, qt, contextmenu, windows-shell

Right now I'm developing a search app using `Qt`, what I want is that right-clicked a file to show the Windows Shell ContextMenu [like this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellcontextmenu.aspx).

But all I can get is `IContextMenu` or `CMenu`. How can I use it in Qt, or transform CMenu or IContextMenu to QMenu.

Answer (score 1):

You could try `#include <Windows.h>` in your Qt project and somehow incorporate the Windows stuff, although incorporating the Windows code with the Qt code would probably be a huge challenge.